# How do I addEventListener to custom actionscript class?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, mxml

I have an actionscript class MyClass that extens NavigatorContent. I instantiate the class as a custom MXML NavigatorContnent component for an Accordion component. MyClass has a Button component that I have tried to attach an event listener to. I want the event to bubble so that I can have the handler in the Accordion component.

**MyClass**

```
package comp
{

  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.events.MouseEvent;

  [Event(name="selectEvent", type="flash.events.Event")]

  public class MyClass extends NavigatorContent
  {

    public function MyClass()
    {
      super();
      btnSelect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, selectClickDispatcher);
    }


    public function selectClickDispatcher(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
      event.currentTarget.dispatchEvent(new Event("selectEvent",true));
    }
  }
}
```

From here I have the instantiated component nested in the Accordion. I am pretty sure the problem is in this class definition because when I set a breakpoint at the selectClickHandler, the code does not break. In case I am wrong I will post the rest of the components.

**Custom component named MySubComp.mxml**

```
<comp:MyClass
    ...I have a few more spark components here and nothing else...
/>
```

**Accordion**

```
<mx:Accordion>

    <fx:Script> //omitted CDATA tags to save space
        protected function selectEventHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            Alert.show("Value Selected");   
        }
    </fx:Script>

        //custom components are in the navs package
        <navs:MySubComp selectEvent = "selectEventHandler(event)"/>

</mx:Accordion>
```

Comment: Where are you defining `btnSelect`?  If it is a skin part, you're going to what to do that `addEventListener` in your override of the `partAdded` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class either needs to extend a `DisplayObject` class, or directly inherit from `EventDispatcher` in order to be able to use events. Forget about implementing `IEventDispatcher` as there's a special piece of black code somewhere that means that `EventDispatcher` is the only class that can set the `target` property of the `Event` class (I've tried it before).

Consider using other alternatives. Events in Flash tend to be slow and create objects all the time. Callbacks are a good system if you need something simple.

```
public class A
{
    public var onSomething:Function = null;
    public function foo():void
    {
        if( this.onSomething != null )
            this.onSomething();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public function B()
    {
        var a:A = new A;
        a.onSomething = this._somethingCalled; // set the callback
        a.init();
    }

    private function _somethingCalled():void
    {
        trace( "hello there" );
    }
}
```

You can also take a look at the Signals project: https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals/wiki

Signals are vastly superior to normal Flash events, and there's no restriction on the type of object that can use them (i.e. non-DisplayObject objects can still add event listeners and dispatch events). It's also faster and has a smaller memory footprint.

Answer (score 2):

You have added the metadata to the class definition

```
[Event(name="selectEvent", type="flash.events.Event")]
```

so all you need to do in mxml is

```
<comp:MyClass selectEvent="event_handler(event)"
..... />
```

In AS3, you add an event listener by

```
myClass.addEventListener("selectEvent", event_handler);
```

P.S. Your class will have to extend EventDispatcher

Comment: It's not a good practice to use "selectEvent" as unspecified string in `addEventListener`, better - to specify `public static const SELECT_EVENT:String = "selectEvent";` in `MyClass` and use event name through reference.

Comment: Yeah.

Ideally, I would inherit the Event class into a custom event and then declare SELECT_EVENT in that class

Better still, I would declare the class to dispatch the "select" event so that the event listener can be added as `myClass.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, event_handler);`

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs the real Actionscript-3 event dispatching to be used >>> [this](http://jeffnehlsen.com/2011/02/actionscript-3-custom-events-explained/) <<< is very helpful. I don't know if it is really slow but it meets the AS-3 standards.